# Frequency of connections between nodes represented by the edge thickness

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a directed graph where some two nodes are connected by multiple edges.

However I would like the two connected nodes to be visualised with only one edge with a property specifying the number of edges between them and possibly a relative edge thickness.

What query do I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: There are separate libraries available to visualize graphs such D3 and Sigma.js

Comment: And what's the problem? Calculate the value by which to set the thickness of the links between nodes? Or in the visualization stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the neo4j browser web ui, there is no command to customize the visualization in that way.

In particular, the Cypher query language is only for performing DB operations, and does not have a way to directly affect visualizations.